# Css/HTML positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Having problems keeping all my stuff in place when I zoom and rezoom in. I would like someone to help me out.

Also how can I align my copyright and contact.etc... at the bottom of my screen.

This is a text based game I am working on all by myself.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
body
{
        background-color: maroon;
        text-align: center;
}
#wrapper
{
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        background-color: gray;
        padding: 5;
        border: 5px solid black;
        width: 940px;
        height: 800px;
}
#wrapper1
{
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        padding: 1;
        border: 2px solid black;
}
#wrapper2
{
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        padding: 1;
        border: 2px solid black;
}

.auto-style4 {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding: 1px 4px;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}
.auto-style6 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
.auto-style7 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 6px;
    border-style: 1px solid black;
}

.auto-style8 {
    border: 3px solid #000000;
}

.auto-style9 {
    margin-top: 0px;
    text-align: right;
}

.auto-style10 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 4px;
    margin-top: 641;
}
</style>
</head>
<body style="margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0; margin-top: 3; margin-bottom: 0">
<div id="wrapper" style="height: 885px" class="auto-style3">
<div id="wrapper1" class="auto-style9" style="height: 178px">

    &nbsp;<img src="TheLast.png" alt="TheLastPic" height="173" width="621" class="auto-style4" style="float: left">
    <table align="right" style="float: right; width: 31%; height: 135px" class="auto-style6" cellpadding="2">
        <tr>
            <td border="1" style="height: 8px; width: 156px;" class="auto-style8">
            Name: Joshua</td>
            <td style="height: 8px; width: 107px;" class="auto-style8">Health: 100%%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 156px; height: 22px;" class="auto-style8">Level: 500</td>
            <td class="auto-style8" style="height: 22px; width: 107px">
            Condition: 100%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 156px; height: 64px;" class="auto-style8">Rations 
            (R): 585,320,005(R)</td>
            <td class="auto-style8" style="width: 107px; height: 64px">Energy: 
            100%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="height: 33px; width: 156px;" class="auto-style8">SP: 22spp</td>
            <td style="height: 33px; width: 107px;" class="auto-style8">Vitality: 100%</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="wrapper2">
    <div class="auto-style7">
        Home | Store | Upgrade | <a href="BackPack.html">BackPack</a> | Players Online | Total Players
</div>
    </div>
        <div class="auto-style10" align="center" style="height: 31px; width: 914px">
            <b>Contact|<a href="Rules.html">Rules/Intro</a>|GameStats</b> <br>© 2015 thelast.com All Rights Reserved
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use "clear:both" in wrapper selector

Comment: Add a JSFiddle or Code Snippet to your question

Comment: Maybe someone is willing to skype and show me how to fix it through voice guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you are making a text-based game in HTML and css, I first urge you to make sure you have actions to prevent any kind of hacking if it is multiplayer. Anyway, using absolute positioning is a great way to go for items that need to be placed in one spot.

```
.example{
    position:absolute;
    top:5px;
    left:5px;
}
```

There is an example of how you can do it, fairly simple, it will display 5px  away from top left corner of the div wrapper. to position from bottom, use something like `bottom:5px;left:5px`.

Comment: This did help me position the bottom copyright thing in the right position. However it didn't help me with my main problem. I need help making it so when I zoom in and out my tables and content and text doesn't reposition; someone said use a wrapper so I did and it still doesn't work.

Comment: I mean like when I'm at 90% the wrapper's and tables shift outside the main wrapper. When I'm at 100% it's perfectly aligned.

Comment: the problem you have is your program isn't made to be dynamic. ways to fix that is by using things like JQuery to change height/width based on screen size. ways of using this include `var width = screen.width / 2;(half of screen width` and `var height = screen.height` and the setting the css of the item to that value `$('#id').css('height',height);`. if you need more in depth answer, show me a picture of what you are trying to create and i might be able to help with a bit more exact script for what you need

Comment: Okay could I get email? And I'll just email you some images of what I'm working on plus I may add a few more questions to the messages since your becoming a great source of help. :)

Comment: yeah shoot me email at jimmyfens@gmail.com

Comment: Okay my friend I emailed you.